# jQuery Hide / Show div that contains php include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Let me first say I am 98% positive I am going about this the wrong way.

First time poster, be gentle. I am working on a website where I want a primitive admin portal back-end where the site can be managed in a single .php page. I have two columns, on the left is a series of stacked nav-pills and on the right is a PHP form to edit site content. Depending on which nav-pill is clicked, the right hand side will display a corresponding PHP form. I need the jQuery function to .empty() the container div called "admin-div" and .toggle() the proper div based on id. The jQuery doesn't seem to be working, and I'm having a hard time grasping why. I am entirely new at jQuery and I'm still a student, so forgive any obvious oversights. Code below for reference. Thanks in advanced! (Sorry if this is off-topic or not a valid question / post, I'm new).

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#geo-btn").click(function(){
            $("#admin-div").empty();
            $("#geo-div").toggle();
            });
        });     

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#school-btn").click(function(){
            $("#admin-div").empty();
            $("#school-div").toggle();
            });
        });



<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-justified">
    <label>Edit Geographic Information</label>
        <li><button id="geo-btn" class="btn btn-warning" >Geography</button></li><br>
        <li><button id="school-btn" class="btn btn-warning" >Schools</button></li><br>
</ul>
<div class="admin-div">
    <div id="geo-div" align="left" class="span8">
        <?php
            require("geo.inc.php");
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="school-div" align="left" class="span8">
        <?php
            require("school.inc.php");
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why empty() $("#admin-div").empty();

Comment: You seem to have some wrong notions. jQuery is a client side technology running in browser. It does not care whether the back end is php or something else. Browser does not see your php includes at all. Therefore the title is WRONG. You better reword the title properly.

Comment: So if the script is in my PHP included header, does the browser not recognize the jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-justified">
    <label>Edit Geographic Information</label>
        <li><button category="geo"  class="btn btn-warning" >Geography</button></li><br>
        <li><button category="school" class="btn btn-warning" >Schools</button></li><br>
</ul>
<div id="admin-div">
    <div id="geo-div" align="left" class="span8">
        <?php
            require("geo.inc.php");
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="school-div" align="left" class="span8" style="display: none;">
        <?php
            require("school.inc.php");
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
        $(".btn").click(function()
        {
            var category = $(this).attr("category")

            $("#admin-div div").hide();
            $("#"+category+"-div").fadeIn();
        });
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: Why multiple $(document).ready() calls? Whole thing can be done inside one call right?

Comment: I'm very new to jQuery, I'm more used to JavaScript. Thanks for sharing this, I'll remember going forward.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you need content switcher so here's an example <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/2kx4w/)**</kbd>

First add `data-rel` attribute to buttons, content of the `data-rel` attribute must match div ID in this case, it don't has to be `data-rel` it could be `data-anything` because it's HTML5 custom data attribute but if you change it don't forget to change the name in the script too.

```
<li><button id="geo-btn" data-rel="geo-div" class="btn btn-warning" >Geography</button></li>
<li><button id="school-btn" data-rel="school-div" class="btn btn-warning" >Schools</button></li>
```

Second add this piece of CSS

```
.span8:first-child {
  display: block;
}
.span8 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

Third and last add this script just before the `</body>` tag

```
<script>
  $(function() { // <-- Short for $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
      $('#'+$(this).data('rel')).stop().fadeIn(450).siblings('.span8').stop().fadeOut(450);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up using something like this, where .meat is a class defined as hidden and each of the divs containing the content has a class of meat, so any time any of the buttons are clicked, all of the divs are hidden cause of their class declaration. Thank you very much for your response, I'm just learning jQuery and it's good to know various ways.










$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#geobut").click(function(){
     $(".meat").hide();
    $("#geo").show();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#schoolbut").click(function(){
    $(".meat").hide();
    $("#school").show();
  });